# How to render Partial View into MVC Razor TabPanel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In my .cshtml main View, i have a TabPanel  supposed to cantain a GridPanel. The gridPanel is defined in .cshtml PartialView. My question is how to display the gridPanel in the TabPanel defined in the main view?
My code looks like:

mainView.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.warning>
//...
TabPanel lowerPanel = new TabPanel
        {
            Title = "Lower Panel",
            Region = Region.South,
            // .....

            Items = 
            {
                // Call the partial view here to display gridPanel
            }
        };
```

_gridPanelPartialView.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.warning>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            source
        </th>
       //....

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.source)
        </td>
       //...
}

</table>
```

Comment: What is the type of `Items`?  Are you trying to store the contents of the partial there or are you trying to display right then and there?  Also you need to wrap `TabPanel` block in `@{...}`.

Comment: @Ballbin items could be any form supported by TabPanel. One of my items will be the gridPanel defined in the partial view. And  TabPanel block is already in @{...}. the code run fine i get the main view just missig how to display in the lowerPanel TabPanel